# MySQL update query locks table for insertion

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I am in a problematic situation and found dozens of questions on same topic, but may b i am not able to understand those solutions as per my issue.

I have a system built in Codeigniter, and it does the following

codeigniter->start_transaction()

```
        UPDATE T SET A = 1, MODIFIED = NOW() 
        WHERE PK IN 
                ( SELECT PK FROM 
                                (SELECT PK, LAST_INSERT_ID(PK) FROM T 
                                    where FK = 31 AND A=0 AND R=1 AND R_FK = 21 
                                    AND DEAD = 0 LIMIT 0,1) AS TBL1 
                ) and A=0 AND R = 1 AND R_FK = 21 AND DEAD = 0

    -- what this query does is , it takes a row dynamically which is not dead yet,
 --and not assigned and it's linked to 21 id (R_FK) from R table, 
-- when finds the row, update it to be marked as assigned (A=1). 
-- PK = LAST_INSERT_ID(PK) ensures that last_insert_id is updated with this row id, so i can retrieve it from PHP
```

GOTO MODULE B

```
MODULE B {

INSERT INTO T(A,B,C,D,E,F,R,FK,R_FK,DEAD,MODIFIED) VALUES(ALL VALUES)
 -- this line gives me lock wait timeout exceeded.
}
```

MySQL version is 5.1.63-community-log
Table T is an INNODB table and has only one normal type index on FK field, and no foreign key constraints are there. PrimaryKey (PK) field is an auto_increment field.

I get lock wait timeout in the above case , and that is due to first transactional update holding lock on table, how can i avoid lock on table with that update query ,while using transactions, **I cannot commit the transaction until i receive response from MODULE B .**

I don't have much detailed knowledge about DB and structural things, so please bear with me if i said something not making sense.

--UPDATE--
-- TABLE T Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `T` (
  `PK` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FK` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `P` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEAD` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `A` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MODIFIED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `R` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `R_FK` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`PK`),
  KEY `FK_REFERENCE_54` (`FK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Indexes Information

SHOW INDEX FROM T;

1- Field FK, Cardinality 65 , NULL => Yes , Index_Type => BTRee
2- Field PK, Cardinality 11153, Index_Type => BTRee
```

Comment: Is this table MyISAM or InnoDb ?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention , it's InnoDB

Comment: Rows are locked because you are updating the primary key column to 'last-insert-id` value: `PK = LAST_INSERT_ID(PK)` . Could you explain why do you do this at all ?  I cannot imagine why anyone want to change PK values. PK is PK - it uniquely identifies a row in the table, it should never change (but this is only my opinion).

Comment: because i need the id of the row dynamically updated, so by this way , it will be the last_insert_id, so i can retrieve it from php and use for later processes.

Comment: Could you also show a structure of the table `T` ? Primarily definitions of indexes ? Is there an index  on `A`  column ?

Comment: i have added the table structure as an update , and indexes information , and there is no index on "A" Column

Comment: @kordirko if there is a way to change the query to only lock rows being updated , instead of locking whole table, the result i want is to get one of the available rows which matches the criteria, update it's A=1, and get the id of the row modified.  so this way whole table won't be locked and i will be able to insert new rows in that table

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce your issue but without success. Updating the primary key value doesn't lock the whole table as I thought. Could you also give a version of your MySql ?

Comment: @kordirko mysql version : 5.1.63-community-log, and yes the process is simply as i mentioned in post, because i executed following directly in mysql  and it gave me same timeout, START TRANSACTION, UPDATE QUERY, INSERT QUERY (with another connection to mysql ) and a lock wait timeout received

Comment: Like it was said above, you should never ever touch a PK, whatever you think. If you need to update it dynamically, then you are doing something essentially wrong.

Comment: @YourCommonSense , I updated the query and removed the part to update PK, instead moved LAST_INSERT_ID(PK) to the inner query , just to update the last_insert_id. but still the same, i am receiving lock wait timeout on insert

Comment: @kordirko I checked more and even replaced LAST_INSERT_ID with a variable to save the PK value, doesn't help , then i tested if i remove the subquery and put id directly, it doesn't lock the table , so it works, but i need to find id's and update A=1 in one step, so if you can help me somehow improve the query to not lock the table while update  and also bring me PK value. it will solve my problem, i don't have much knowledge about databases , but i think avoiding subquery should be possible

Comment: One advice is: keep the transaction as short as possible - do the Update and then commit immediately. A default wait-timeout is 50 second. If you are getting wait timeout errors again and again, that means, that the update keeps rows locked for more than 50 seconds. Unfortunately locking issues in MySql sometimes become tricky, because MySql apart from locking individual rows only, very oftem can lock all rows scaned by the command (even rows not picked by the WHERE condition), and also index ranges (or even whole index) in cases when indexed column is a part of the WHERE condition.